# how in #ifdef identifier and #ifndef identifier declare identifiers

Tags: c++, dll, header-files, dllexport, ifndef

```cpp
#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
// How to determine the identifier above?  
// Where did `MATHLIBRARY_API` came from?
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Another example:

```cpp
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    // same question here.where BUILD_DLL came from?
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)     
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

I'm working on making a header file for a DLL, and I'm really stuck on this.
I'm confused about what identifier I should use after `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` directives.

Comment: It came from literally right there. `#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)` defines `MATHLIBRARY_API`, an instruction to the preprocessor that it must replace the  `MATHLIBRARY_API` token with `__declspec(dllimport)` anywhere the preprocessor finds it after the definition.

Comment: you first ask for `MATHLIBRARY_API` which is `#define`d in your code but then you ask for `#ifndef` / `#ifdef`. One is defining the symbol the latter tests if it is defined.

Comment: I suspect the first one is actually asking about `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` rather than `MATHLIBRARY_API`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking where `MATHLIBRARY_API` comes from seems incongruous, as it's defined right there in the code.

I *suspect* you're actually asking about *using* `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` instead, since you later asked about `BUILD_DLL` (which is also a *using* case). So I'll base this answer on that.

Definitions *typically* happen in one of two places:

1. From `#define` earlier in the process. You can see that in operation in your code where it defines, for example, `DLL_EXPORT`.
2. As a compiler flag such as `-D MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS`.

In terms of the actual names you can use, these are identifiers so have to follow certain rules set down in the standard<sup>(1)</sup>.

You are also responsible for managing "collisions" of those names between individual parts of the compilation process (such as your code and third-party code). So, if two header files that you use each had different definitions for TRUE, that could cause issues:

```c
#define TRUE 1
#define TRUE (!0)
```

As an *example* of using this (*very* similar to your `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS/MATHLIBRARY_API` example, I suspect), see the following code:

```cpp
#ifdef ACCESS_PRIVATE
    # define PRIVATE
#else
    # define PRIVATE static
#endif

void public_function() { /* code goes here */ }
PRIVATE void private_function() { /* code goes here */ }
```

If you compile that with `g++ -c -o file.o file.c`, then `private_function()` will be static, so not visible outside of the current translation unit.

However, if you added `-D ACCESS_PRIVATE` to the compiler flags, then the function would *not* be static and you would be able to access it from other code that you link.

This sort of thing is often done for unit tests of otherwise private functions.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> For allowable characters in identifiers, see the current iteration of the standard at time of this answer, `C++20 5.10 Identifiers` (or equivalent section in other iterations).

This is functionally defined as having the first character drawn from the set (C allows for extra implementation-defined characters, C++ apparently does not):

- Any upper or lower-case letter, `[A-Za-z]`.
- An underline character `_`.
- Any universal character name in predefined ranges (see the standard for full list), such as `\U0001f602` being . However, keep in mind certain universal characters (such as combining characters) are disallowed in the *first* position of an identifier.

That character is then followed by zero or more subsequent characters which are either:

- Any digit, `[0-9]`.
- Any character from the "first character" set above, with "first character" restrictions removed.

Answer (score 1):

The `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` are passive, they don't create identifiers, they test for the presence of an identifier. If you want to create an identifier, use `#define`.

In many compilers or preprocessors, they have a table for identifiers.  The `#ifdef` is the same as `#if defined`, which means that you are testing if an identifier is defined, meaning that it is in the table.

### Edit 1: Example - Header guard

To prevent header files from being including multiple times by the same source file, there is a pattern called an *include guard*:

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H
//...
#endif // MYFILE_H
```

The first line tests if the identifier `MYFILE_H` is defined.  The second line will create the identifier if the identifier is not defined.  This results in the content being ignored if the identifer has been defined.

Comment: thank you.but how to determine an identifier for #define?is it like declaring a variable?means we can use the rules of choosing variable names?

Comment: In a good C++ reference, it will define an *identifier*.  For *simplicity*, the text following a `#define` is usually an identifier, such as `#define RECTANGLE_H`, where `RECTANGLE_H` is the identifier.